# How to get eloquent relationship using parent pivot value as where condition

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pivot, relationship

I am trying to get a hasMany relationship in Eloquent, but using the value of the parent's pivot table in a where clause.

For example

```
class Page
{
    public function modules()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Module::class)->withPivot('sun_id');
    }
}

class Module
{
    public function settings()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ModuleSetting::class)
            ->where('sun_id', $this->pivot->sun_id);
    }
}

$page = Page::with('modules.settings')->get();
```

The `$this->pivot-sun_id` in the 'settings' function obviously doesn't work.  How can I achieve this?  Would I need to write a raw DB statement when I declare $page or is there a more "Eloquent-esque" method?

Thanks

**Edit**

Attached is my table schema.
[image]

- *pages*: Table is self explanatory. Contains a list of pages
- *modules*: Modules are page elements. A block of text or a calendar for example
- *module_page*: Pivot table to bind modules to a page
- *module_settings*.  A page can have more than one module of the same type. So two calendars for example. the module settings table defines
  settings for the calendar, such as colour, should the calendar be
  downloadable etc.

Comment: Could you share a little more about the relevant relations and tables? For example `ModelSetting`, `Setting` perhaps? We might be able to give a proper answer. Possible you need to look at [custom intermediat table models](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have removed the previous response since I'm duplicating a fair bit here. I believe you can use a custom collection method to achieve the page specific results you desire, all while retaining an eloquent style response and keeping your call fairly simple.  This seems to be working for me.

Unfortunately, I don't believe it's possible to do what you're asking strictly with eloquent relationships, because once you get into the modules, there is no way to "reach back" to get the page id.

You will notice there are two `withModuleSettings()` methods, one for a collection of pages, and one for an individual page.

Create a new file:

App/PageCollection.php

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;

class PageCollection extends Collection
{
    // this will load the module settings based on page id
    public function withModuleSettings()
    {
        foreach ($this as $p => $page) {
            $this[$p]->withModuleSettings();
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Your models:

```php
class Page extends Model
{
    // ... 

    public function modules()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Module::class)->withPivot('module_instance');
    }

    // override the default collection instance with our own
    public function newCollection(array $models = [])
    {
        return new PageCollection($models);
    }

    // this will load the module settings based on page id
    public function withModuleSettings()
    {
        // this page id
        $id = $this->id;

        foreach ($this->modules as $m => $module) {

            // get module instance from pivot
            $instance = $module->pivot->module_instance;

            // load relations
            $this->modules[$m]->load(['settings' => function($query) use ($id, $instance) {
                $query
                    ->where('module_settings.page_id',$id)
                    ->where('module_settings.module_instance',$instance)
                ;
            }]);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}

class Module extends Model
{
    // ...

    public function settings()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            ModuleSetting::class,
            ModulePage::class,
            'module_id',         // first key
            'module_instance',   // second key
            'id',                // local key
            'module_instance'    // second local key
        );
    }
}

class ModulePage extends Model
{
    // define the table name since Laravel expects it to be 'module_pages'
    protected $table = 'module_page';
}

class ModuleSetting extends Model
{
    // ...
}
```

The action:

```php
$pages = Page::with('modules')->get()->withModuleSettings();
```

Works with single pages too:

```php
$page = Page::with('modules')->first()->withModuleSettings();
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. It is very nearly working.  The only problem is, module_instance in the module_settings table is not necessarily unique.  It is only unique per page.  For example, I could add a calendar on page_id 1 and it will have a module_instance of 1. Then I could add the same module on page_id 2 and it too will have a module instance of 1.  This is resulting in settings for modules on both pages being returned.  Do I need to make module_instance unique or is there a way to filter out settings for one page only?

Comment: I think you may need to do it the other way around. See my edits. I hope this helps.

Comment: That would work perfectly. You are a legend.  I now just need to look through both of your examples and learn what the functions are actually doing. Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: I decided that it would be best to make sure all module_instance ids were unique (for reasons other than mentioned here), and therefore resorted to your first answer - which works better for me. However, when I add two modules of the same type to one page - even with unique module_instance ids, the settings contains items from both instances.  Now that I have unique module_instance ids, is there an easy way to prevent that?

Comment: here is a fiddle demonstrating the problem. I have one page and one module. The module is added to the page twice and given different settings, but the output shows both settings for both modules. https://implode.io/aDOCa9

Comment: I really appreciate your help with this matticustard.  I can safely say I would never achieve this without help.  The edited code above is throwing an error Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::withModuleSettings(). I notice that the "newCollection" method is never called. Could this be the problem?

Comment: Sorry. My bad. I had a typo. However, this seems to be getting settings where the 'page_id' is unique. It should be the 'module_instance' that is unique.

Comment: You asked in the very beginning `is there a way to filter out settings for one page only`.  Are you saying settings for an individual page may have different `page_ids` within module settings?  The `settings` relationship uses the unique `model_instance` and that is what is `->load()`ed before being filtered by `page_id`.

Comment: I may have worded that badly.  So a single page will have multiple modules. Each time a new module is added to a page, it is given a unique 'module_instance' id. Sometimes, the same module can be added to a single page, but again, each instance will have a unique module_instance id. The settings are unique to a module_instance id.  so if a calendar module was added to the page twice, they would each have their own unique settings. I have copied and pasted your code exactly as it is - but where I have two of the same modules assigned to a page, each contains settings for both instances

Comment: Matticustard, here is an example of what I mean. I am outputting the pages, modules, module_page and module_settings table so you can see i have one page and one module. That one module is assigned to the page twice and settings have been given to each module instance. However, when I output the page, i have one page containing two instances of the module, but each instance contains both sets of settings. https://implode.io/aDOCa9

Comment: Okay, I've updated the changes.  All changes were to the page model.

Comment: That is it. That is exactly what i need. Thanks again for all your continued support.  I really appreciate it. I promise I won't bother you any more. :)

Comment: My pleasure!  Off to bed for me.